# Generating a random number when 2 exe's are being executed simultaneously

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve the following problem : 
2 files are given : "names.txt" and "phone.txt". In "names.txt" there is a name on each line and in "phone.txt" there is a phone number on each line.
name.c reads line by line from "names.txt", phone.c reads line by line from "phone.txt". Both of name.c and phone.c will need to syncronize their execution(using fifo communication channels) such that there will be printed a name and a phone number.

I've tried swaping fifo1 with fifo2 100 times as this seemed to be the problem the last time, but this time with no success

this it the part of phone.c using fifo channels :

```
if (-1==mkfifo("fifo1",0600))
{
    if (errno!=EEXIST)
        perror("crearea a esuat");
}

if (-1==mkfifo("fifo2",0600))
{
    if (errno!=EEXIST) perror("crearea a esuat");
}

fifo1=open("fifo1",O_RDONLY);
fifo2=open("fifo2",O_WRONLY);

for (int j=0;j<=n;j++)
{
    read(fifo1,&ch,1);

    printf("%s",string[j]);

    write(fifo2,&ch,1);
}
```

and this is the part using fifo channels from name.c

```
if (-1==mkfifo("fifo1",0600) )
{
    if (errno!=EEXIST)
        perror("crearea a esuat");
}

fifo1=open("fifo1",O_WRONLY);
fifo2=open("fifo2",O_RDONLY);

for (int j=0;j<=n;j++)
{
    printf("\n%s ",string[j]);
    write(fifo1,&ch,1);
    read(fifo2,&ch,1);
}
```

It prints a random number like "2742" and then the contents of "name.txt", but no phone numbers are printed after each name.

Comment: You probably want to `fflush` after the `printf`.

Comment: You're reading and writing single characters via the read/write calls.  You aren't checking that the `open()` calls succeed; you aren't heeding the values returned by `read()` or `write()`.  There's nothing shown that's reading from the files mentioned. The random-ish number probably comes from uninitialized data in some form.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  What you've provided is a bit too minimal, I fear.

Comment: David Schwartz thank you, i forgot about the fflush.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler, i'm sorry if my question was a bit unclear, it was my first time posting. Anyway, thanks for your help, i'll keep that in mind in the future!